# Is there a "generics-like" feature in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, generics

I'm trying to create a list class in C++ similar to the lists in Java. Is there a way I can have it be able to list whatever object it wants to? The class resizes arrays to create the list, but what I need to do is find out the kind of object that's needed to store.

Comment: [C++ templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)?

Comment: Templates can certainly do the job (though comparing templates to Java generics is a bit like comparing a Formula 1 race car to a child's pedal car with a number painted on the side).

Comment: [not writing templates in c++ is like watching porn without mastrubating.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=10483030#10483030), felt this quote was relevant.

Comment: Standard template library or templates, depends on your need (I can't really see it from the question).

Comment: Isn't the generic feature in Java learned from C++ template?

Comment: @YuHao: I think both came from Ada generics; Java's generics seem a lot closer to Ada 83 generics than to C++ templates.

Comment: [Templates vs. generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B#Templates_vs._generics)

Comment: @YuHao I liked "Templates are Turing-complete" from that link.

Comment: I want to point out that C++'s "generics" are among the best. You can do a whole lot more than what you're asking here.

Comment: They are completely different things, despite the syntax. C++ templates create new type;, generate new code; and don't really fit properly into the type system. Java Generics constrain existing types; don't generate any code at all; and are *part of* the type system. You cannot compare them in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, C++ has templates that can be used to create generic containers roughly similar to Java generic containers.

While your immediate reaction might be to assume that `std::list` is similar to a Java list, that would be a mistake. In Java, a list basically just means a sequence. In C++, a `std::list` is a linked list (which is rarely useful). Most of the time you want to use an `std::vector` (which is more like Java's `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is, and it's called [Templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)

Comment: And it's actually **far** superior to generics.

Comment: How do I tell which kind of object the Template actually is?

Comment: I am sure your C++ book covers that. You could have a look at it first.

Comment: @MonetR.Adams you get a c++ book or a tutorial and learn about them.

Comment: @MonetR.Adams: If you don't have a good `C++` book look here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/445976)